# Salesforce lightning displays extra characters on click of Change record type hyperlink

Tags: salesforce1-app

Query: Salesforce by default provides change recordtype hyperlink based on Record Type (Data type) field. In lightning experience when this hyperlink is clicked I could see some extra characters like(%) in the Record Name.

Attached image with same issue... How can we get rid of those extra characters or is it expected behaviour...

Thanks in advance for your help!!!

Comment: I don't see the image you put in your post. Can you please **[edit]** your post and try again?

Comment: I can't figure out how to reproduce this, oddly, but I am fairly sure I've seen what you're talking about and it's just a normal artifact of how Lightning Experience URLs are constructed.